# Vectorizing calculations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, cross-validation

I'm trying to calculate group averages inside of the cross-validation scheme, but this iterating method is extremely slow as my dataframe contains more than 1mln rows. Is it possible to vectorize this calculation? Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = np.column_stack([np.arange(1,101), np.random.randint(1,11, 100),np.random.randint(1,101, 100)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'group','total'])
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(df.shape[0], n_folds=3, shuffle = True)
f = {'total': ['mean']}
df['fold'] = 0
df['group_average'] = 0
for train_index, test_index in kf:
    df.ix[train_index, 'fold'] = 0
    df.ix[test_index, 'fold'] = 1
    aux = df.loc[df.fold == 0, :].groupby(['group'])
    aux2 = aux.agg(f)
    aux2.reset_index(inplace = True)
    aux2.columns = ['group', 'group_average']
    for i, row in df.loc[df.fold == 1, :].iterrows():
        new = aux2.ix[(aux2.group == row.group),'group_average']
        if new.empty == True:
            new = 0
        else:
            new = new.values[0]
        df.ix[i, 'group_average'] = new
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and output data so we run run your code?

Comment: @Khris Sorry, I edited the code, you should be able to run it now

Comment: Tried applying a lambda function but that's even slower.

Comment: Should `group_average` be the same value within each group or should it be varying?

Comment: It should vary within one group because of splitting into 5 folds. For example, group average for the 5th group should be calculated using first 4 folds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `for i, row in df.loc[df.fold == 1, :].iterrows():`-loop with this:

```
df0 = pd.merge(df[df.fold == 1],aux2,on='group').set_index('id')
df = df.set_index('id')
df.loc[(df.fold == 1),'group_average'] = df0.loc[:,'group_average_y']
df = df.reset_index()
```

This gives me the same result as your code and is almost 7 times faster.

Comment: Thanks, I was playing around with merge, but  did not think of this solution.